# State variables in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there any way to have a state variable in VIM? Consider:

```
" Relative line numbers in Normal mode, absolute in Insert mode. Ctrl-N to toggle 
set relativenumber
autocmd InsertEnter * :set number
autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber
inoremap <C-n> <C-o>:call NumberToggle()<cr>
nnoremap <C-n> :call NumberToggle()<cr>
function! NumberToggle()
  if(useRelNums != 1)
    let useRelNums=1
    set number
  else
    let useRelNums=0
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc
```

Of course, `useRelNums` is undefined. I would like to keep this variable defined between calls to the `NumberToogle()` function, i.e. a state variable. How is this done? I'm sure that I could repurpose some other VIM variable as a workaround (such as the state of `paste` for a bad example) but I would prefer a real solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may introduce global variables with `let g:use_rel_numbers` or `let g:use_rel_numbers=1`. local variables would be better i think - `let b:use_rel_numbers` for example and `setlocal relativenumber`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the settings themselves as your desired state variables... they're boolean, and exclusive.  turning on 'number', turns off 'relativenumber', and vice-versa.

So you could do:

```
function! ToggleNumbers()
    if &number
        set relativenumber       " was number, now relanum
    elseif &relativenumber
        set norelativenumber     " was relanum, now nothing
    else
        set number               " was nothing, now number
    endif
endfunction
```

A nice three-state toggle. (triggle?)   (troggle?)  {shrug} your call...

AND... this interfaces seamlessly with your desired autocmds since they affect the number/relativenumber booleans too... taa daa!

> I like triggle...

Comment: @epsilon makes a good point, probably should be `setlocal ...` really.  Uh... I was copying the variable scope style of the author...yeah... that's what I was doing... yeah...  But the vim help states that number/relativenumber are local to the window anyways.   doesn't hurt though, certainly helps convey the intent that they are PER windows/buffer/thingamabob.

Comment: Thanks, lornix. Using the current state of `relativenumber` won't help as the state is reset when entering / leaving Insert mode. That is why I am trying to do something more elaborate.